Passing a Date Variable, into another variable value in Matillion
We are calling secured API profiles through Matillion Query profile. I wanted to pass the date value to a filter. That date variable will be used in another variable value.
But I am not finding any possibilities to do that, can you please help me with this if you can.
I tried by adding the bearer token to bash script and filter variable value. However, I was unable to get any positive sign to pass the date variable

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
